# underscore template javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to call a html file and  pass values dynamically. I have created a template in javascript. However it is not working. I have another js file where the key vaue pair have been created.

Inside HTML

```
<div class="form-box" id="login-box">
<div class="header .bg-green"><span class="appname"></span></div>
<form method="get" id="vclogin" action="">
 <div class="form-group">
       <input type="checkbox" id="rememberCHK" name="remember_me" > <%=CBID%> </>
       </div>
    <button id="btnlogin" type="button" class="btn bg-olive btn-block">
        <%=SignMeID%></button>
</div>
<div class="footer">                
    <p>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="resetpass"><%=ForgotPWD%></a></p>
    <a href="" id="newreg" class="text-center"><%=Register%></a>
</div>
</form>
```

Inside js file 1

```
var temp;
        temp = _.template(HTMLTemplate, {
            CBID:lang.checkboxID,
            SignMeID:lang.SignMeID,
            ForgotPWD:lang.ForgotPassword,
            Register:lang.Newregistration
        });
        $('#login-box').append(temp);
```

Inside the 2nd JS file

```
define({
    "root": {
        checkboxID: "Remember me",
        SignMeID: "Sign me in",
        ForgotPassword:"I forgot my password",
        Newregistration:"Register a new membership"
    },
    'fr': true
});
```

Looking forward to some code fix